# Function write() inconsistent with number notation

Tags: r, formatting, scientific-notation

Consider the following script:

```
list_of_numbers <- as.numeric()
for(i in 1001999498:1002000501){
  list_of_numbers <- c(list_of_numbers, i)
}
write(list_of_numbers, file = "./list_of_numbers", ncolumns = 1)
```

The file that is produced looks like this:

```
[user@pc ~]$ cat list_of_numbers
1001999498
1001999499
1.002e+09
...
1.002e+09
1.002e+09
1.002e+09
1002000501
```

I found a couple more ranges where R does not print consistently the number format.

Now I have the following questions:

Is this a bug or is there an actual reason for this behavior?
Why just in certain ranges, why not every number above x?

I know how I can solve this like this:

```
options(scipen = 1000)
```

But are there more elegant ways than setting global options? Without converting it to a dataframe and changing the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, R chooses the shortest representation.

More precisely, in `?options` one can read:

> fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than `scipen`
>   digits wider.

So when `scipen` is 0 (the default), the shortest notation is preferred.

Note that you can get the scientific notation of a number `x` with `format(x, scientific = TRUE)`.

In your case:

- `1001999499` is 10 characters long whereas its scientific notation `1.001999e+09` is longer (12 characters), so the decimal notation is kept.
- `1001999500`: scientific notation is `1.002e+09`, which is shorter.
- ..................... (scientific notation stays equal to `1.002e+09`, hence shorter)
- `1002000501`: `1.002001e+09` is longer.

You may ask: how come that `1001999500` is formatted as `1.002e+09` and not as `1.0019995e+09`? It's simply because there is also an option that controls the number of significant digits. It is named `digits` and its default value is 7. Since `1.0019995` has 8 significant digits, it is rounded up to `1.002`.

The simplest way to ensure that decimal notation is kept without changing global options is probably to use `format`:

```
write(format(list_of_numbers, scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE), 
      file = "./list_of_numbers")
```

---

Side note: you didn't need a loop to generate your `list_of_numbers` (which by the way is not a list but a vector). Simply use:

```
list_of_numbers <- as.numeric(1001999498:1002000501)
```