# R converts number to exponential notation when exporting to CSV, then reads in as NA

Tags: r, scientific-notation, readr

I'm working with data in R that I need to go back and forth from *.csv* files with. Several of the columns represent years, and for some reason, when I save as a *.csv* using `readr::write_csv()`, the year 2000 (and no other years) saves in exponential notation (`2.00E+03`). Then, when I read the file back into R with `read_csv()`, it reads all of these values in as `NA`.

I've been able to manually convert back to 2000 using `is.na()`, but this is tedious to have to do each time. What's going on here, and is there any way I can make it so R reads and writes this correctly?

Comment: Can you provide the reproducible code that shows the error? When I run `data.frame(year = sample(1999:2001, 10, TRUE)) %>%
  write_csv("[mydesktoplocation]test.csv")` everything writes and reads just fine.

Comment: You should check that the output of `getOption("scipen")` is 0.

Comment: I checked and getOption("scipen") was indeed set to 0. I tried your code Steven and it worked, but tried mine again to no avail. However, the code you posed makes year an integer variable, where my data had it as numeric. Turning the year variables into integer variables solved the issue.

Comment: I think it's quite the same story as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648474/function-write-inconsistent-with-number-notation): the shortest notation is preferred. The only difference is that `readr` does not use the exact same scientific form as base R, e.g. 2000 becomes `2e3`, which is 2 characters shorter than `2e+03` (base R). As a result `write_csv` tends to write more numbers in scientific notation than `write.csv`.

Comment: However, as far as I can see `read_csv` has no problems to read numbers in scientific notation.